# Like Button - Permission

Tags: facebook, permissions

Could somebody explain me please where you can change the settings for likes or what should I do to get the permission from a user to view his likes?

Comment: can you be more clear... are you using FB API...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/
this explains the different permissions available in the Facebook API

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ is the main authentication document

`user_likes` is the permission you're probably looking for